# db.search & wildcard character & lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am doing db.search and I would like search in such a way that any status ( field here ) would come into the result, so I want to use Wildcard "*", can anyone please help me here

below should work ?

```
@contains(Status;"*")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find any non-empty status, you don't need any wildcarding. Just use this:

```
Status <> ""
```

If all you care about is existence of the Status field, whether it's filled in or empty, you can use

```
@IsAvailable(Status)
```

Comment: Even empty is permitted then what would be the case ?

Comment: Where is the sense in searching everything that contains or does not contain a value? This means searching everything... Just omit the phrase for the Status- Field if it does not matter for your search...

Comment: Thanks Torsten, Now my query is that I want to check for the field as well like it could be Status field, or could be StatusText, or anything in terms of status, will it be possible to check this using @contains(Status*;"in Progress") ??

Comment: No, you can't do that with a db.search. You will have to write a loop that examines all the NotesDocuments in the database, with an inner loop that looks at the document.Items() array and examines every item.

Comment: As far as just checking for the presence of absence of the field Status goes, you can use @IsAvailable(Status). But again, you cannot wildcard field/item names. If you want to check for just Status and StatusText, you can use @IsAvailable(Status) | @IsAvailable(StatusText)